# minicart js - applying discount when buying multiple items

Tags: javascript, php, html, cart

I have implemented minicart js into my website, and I can add items to the cart and it works properly. What I would like to do, is say when a user adds 2 items at a particular price (say 11.99) it will discount it down to 20.

I know there is a discount function for minicart js but the documentation isn't too clear. I would just like to know the best way to achieve this?

here is the code I'm working with:

```
<?php   
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "store_scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 

    $dynamicList = '';
    $sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM products where category = 'Rings'");
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($productCount > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
            $dynamicList .= '

            <div id="floatedImage">
                <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="images/' . $product_name . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" /></a>
                <p>' . $product_name . '</p>
                <p>€' . $price . '</p>
                <p><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a><p>

                <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@test.com"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $product_name . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $price . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
                        <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
                        <img alt="" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
                </form>

            </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <title>Rings</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="top">
            <?php include('templates/top_template.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="topnav">
            <?php include('templates/topnav_template.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="banner">

        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <p><?php echo $dynamicList ?></p>

        </div>

        <div id="rightSide">
            <?php include('templates/rightSide_template.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <?php include('templates/footer_template.php'); ?>
        </div>  

        <div id="copyrightFooter">
            <?php include('templates/copyrightFooter_template.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <script src="minicart.js"></script>
        <script>
            paypal.minicart.render();   
        </script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```